# NSTaggedPointerString to unsigned integer

Tags: ios, objective-c, casting, unsigned-integer, openurl

I am trying to parse a URL query component to an unsigned integer. When trying to cast the string extracted from the URL (an NSTaggedPointerString), to unsigned integer, the program crashes with

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSTaggedPointerString
>   unsignedIntegerValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance XXX

My application:openURL:options: method in my AppDelegate is below:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)app
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
            options:(NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey,id> *)options {

    NSURLComponents *components = [NSURLComponents componentsWithURL:url resolvingAgainstBaseURL:NO];

    NSMutableDictionary *queryItemDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:components.queryItems.count];

    for (NSURLQueryItem *queryItem in components.queryItems) {
        [queryItemDict setObject:queryItem.value forKey:queryItem.name];
    }

    if ([[queryItemDict allKeys] containsObject:@"selectedSection"]) {
        NSUInteger selectedSection = 0;
        NSLog(@"%@",[[queryItemDict objectForKey:@"selectedSection"] class]);
        selectedSection = [[queryItemDict objectForKey:@"selectedSection"] unsignedIntegerValue];
    }


    return YES;
}
```

I have tested this in a blank iOS Xcode project and registered the URL scheme "test" like so
[image: register URL ios]

My test url is `test://selectedSection=0`.

I can upload the sample project if needed, but the above two steps are all that is needed to reproduce. Am I not casting the NSString to unsigned integer correctly?

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation for `NSString`? There is no `unsignedIntegerValue` method.

Comment: Thanks. I was able to cast the positive `NSInteger` to `NSUInteger`.
`selectedSection = (NSUInteger)[[queryItemDict objectForKey:@"selectedSection"] integerValue];`